# Error "Object Reference not set to an Instance of an object" on read from DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, instance-variables, object-reference

Ok so I just did a quick test to see if my code was set to read properly from the DataGrid, and it does, but once it finishes reading I get the error `"Object reference not set to an Instance of an object"` and I'm not sure what it's referring to. Is it because the loop continues after the `rows` has reached the end of the DataGrid?

```
public static void UploadFromExtrernalSource(PlantAreaCode_CreateView PACCreate)
{
    // For each row in the DataGrid, and for each column, stores the information in a string.
    for (int rows = 0; rows < PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
        {
            string value = PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(value + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Also when I print to console, it prints each value on a new line. Why?

Comment: are you trace the code?check the actual rows and cells count

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking. The amount of columns and rows are not set, as this will be used on multiple tables.

Comment: Console.WriteLine always print a value in newline.Try Console.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem1 :** You are trying to convert the `null` value from one of the cells into `String`.

**Solution1 :** before converting cell value into `String` do a null check.

**Problem 2:**  you are using `Console.WriteLine()` method to display each cell value.so that it prints each cell value in a new `Row/Line`.

**Solution 2:** you need to use `Console.Write()` method instead of `Console.WriteLine()` to print cell values, and once after printing all cell values from a given row you need to use `Console.WriteLine()` to print new line.

**Suggestion:** you don't need to declare the string variable `value` each time in a for loop, so you can move the string variable declaration out of the loop.

Try This:

```
public static void UploadFromExtrernalSource(PlantAreaCode_CreateView PACCreate)
{
    // For each row in the DataGrid, and for each column, stores the information in a string.
    String value = String.Empty;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
        {
            if(PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value!=null)
            { 
              value=PACCreate.dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value;
              Console.Write(value + ","); 
            }
            else 
            { value=String.Empty; }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();//it prints a new line 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that for me, really cleared up my understanding of what was actually happening here :)

Answer (score 0):

hey i think you are trying to convert null value of a cell into string . try to check for the null before converting it to the string hope this will help !